# Is there any other typeface with distinct math italic letters besides CM and its descendants?

Tags: unicode-math, italic

The only case I can think of off the top of my head would be using Euler as the math face, but I’m wondering if perhaps some other typefaces have visually distinct glyphs in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols range.

Per request, here is an example showing `cmti10` (top) and `cmmi10` (bottom). `cmmi10` has slightly widened letterforms compared to its text counterpart.

[image]

Comment: Distinct in what sense? Can you show with a cm example? Also, the "alphanumeric" part could perhaps be mentioned in the title?

Comment: I see some subtle differences in XITS/STIX and STIX Two's Mathematical Alphanumeric Italics vs their text italics variants.

Comment: The CM example is a bit subtle: the letters are slightly wider (most obvious in the rounded letters like C, O, G and Q). I'll add a picture to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could start a list.

`albatross U+1D44E` can give us a list of fonts.

On my system:

[image: MAS MIS]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\textmis{ℎ}

\newcommand\showsample[1]{%
\color{blue}#1 & \newfontfamily{\myfont}{#1}\myfont\textmis \\ %
}

\begin{document}

MAS: Mathematical Italic Small (text mode)

---

\rowcolors{1}{blue!15}{blue!5}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\showsample{Asana Math}
\showsample{Cambria}
\showsample{Cambria Math}
\showsample{Catrinity}
\showsample{Code2003}
\showsample{Concrete Math}
\showsample{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
%\showsample{DejaVu Serif}
%\showsample{DejaVu Serif Condensed}
\showsample{Erewhon Math}
\showsample{Fira Math}
\showsample{FreeSerif}
%\showsample{Garamond\-Math}
\showsample{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\showsample{KpMath}
\showsample{Latin Modern Math}
\showsample{Libertinus Math}
\showsample{NewComputerModernMath}
\showsample{Noto Sans Math}
\showsample{Quivira}
\showsample{Segoe UI Symbol}
\showsample{STIX}
\showsample{STIX Math}
\showsample{STIX Two Math}
\showsample{Symbola}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\showsample{XCharter Math}
\showsample{XITS Math}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh no, you stole my tick! (+1 anyway:-)

Answer (score 2):

I think most change the side bearings and at least some of the letters. Here is Cambria Italic v Cambria Math Math Italic block, both set as text to avoid any math layout spacing.

[image]

```
 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cam{Cambria}
\newfontfamily\camm{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}


{\cam\itshape abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

{\camm ℎ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any complete(ish) list of fonts with math italics?

Comment: And I rather like the design changes made in the Cambria math italic (the extra swashiness on v, x and y help make them look more mathy to my eyes.

Comment: @DonHosek probably these but I didn't check them all (just sytem fonts, not tex ones)  `fc-list | grep Math| sed -e 's/^[^:]*//'`

Answer (score 0):

##### NewTX: `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

[image]

##### NewPX: `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}`

[image]

##### Fourier: `\usepackage{fourier}`

[image]

The examples have been produced with the following template, so the kerning in the second line (math italic) is not what would be used in math formulas; I chose this in order to get a better comparison of shapes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{<packages>}% specify font packages

\begin{document}

\def\AB{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

{\itshape \uppercase\expandafter{\AB}\AB}

\sbox0{$a$}
{\the\textfont1 \uppercase\expandafter{\AB}\AB}

\end{document}
```